# Round number in the same line of code, not separate

Tags: python, rounding

This returns me

```
distance_ran_in_3_hours = u"{} {}".format(
    summary.get("distance_ran", 0) / self._conversion,
    short_def["distance_ran_display_text"]["english" if self._units == "metric" else "miles"].title()
)
```

It returns me 11.2481902, I want it to look like 11.2. I want to do it in the same code, not separate, like:

```
distance_ran_in_3_hours = float(round(distance_ran_in_3_hours, 1))
```

Comment: `round(float(summary.get("distance_ran", 0) / self._conversion), 1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [string format spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) has a way to do this already.

```py
distance_ran in 3 hours = u"{:.1f} {}".format( # etc
```